# Java int to unsigned byte

Tags: java, integer, byte, signed

Long story short, I'm reading some integer values from one file, then I need to store them in a byte array, for later writing to another file.

For example:

```
int number = 204;
Byte test = new Byte(Integer.toString(number));
```

This code throws:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"204" Radix:10
```

The problem here is that a byte can only store from -127 - 128, so obviously that number is far too high.  What I need to do is have the number signed, which is the value -52, which will fit into the byte.  However, I'm unsure how to accomplish this.

Can anyone advise?

Thanks

Comment: You need to take an array of bytes(usually buffer) .. and have to store each byte

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266756/can-we-make-unsigned-byte-in-java

Comment: if you want to preserve integer's value then you cant cast it to byte ? you need to read all the bytes from file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Convert Int to Unsigned Byte and Back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401550/how-to-convert-int-to-unsigned-byte-and-back)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A much simpler approach is to cast it:

```
int number = 204;
byte b = (byte)number;
System.out.println(b);
```

Prints `-52`.

Answer (score 4):

You can cast it:

```
Byte test = (byte) number;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
  byte b = (byte) ((0xFF) & number);
```

Comment: I don't think you need to `&` it with `0xFF`. It seems to output the same with or without it. And yes, I did try with numbers > 255.

Comment: For the compiler, it's not necessary in Java, for this narrowing conversion from int to byte. However, it explicitly documents that you're *intentionally* using only the least-significant byte.