# Bitwise operators in java only for integer and long?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I wrote following code in Eclipse:

```
byte b = 10;
/* some other operations */
b = ~b;
```

Eclipse wanted a cast to byte in the line of the bitwise complement. It said: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte". I also tried this with other bitwise operations and on other integral types. It was with short and char the same. Only long and integer could use bitwise operations.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: maybe its because the computer has to perform the operation on the entire register which is at least 32bits long?

Comment: Yeah! That might be the reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unary (such as `~`) and binary operators in Java subject their operands to ["unary numeric promotion" (JLS, Section 5.6.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1) and ["binary numeric promotion" (JLS, Section 5.6.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2), respectively, fancy terms for "promote things to at least `int` first".

Specifically, for unary numeric promotion, quoting the JLS section linked above:

> Some operators apply unary numeric promotion to a single operand, which must produce a value of a numeric type:

and

> ... if the operand is of compile-time type byte, short, or char, it is promoted to a value of type int by a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2).

(Binary numeric promotion is similar, operating on both operands.)

So, even if `b` is a `byte`, `~b` is an `int`, because `b`'s value was promoted to an `int` first.

The solution: cast it back to a `byte`:

```
b = (byte) (~b);
```

**Why, Java?**

That leaves the question, why?  It seems for the operators I can find, the JVM bytecode instructions for operating on `byte`s, `short`s, and `char`s simply do not exist.  For example, the unary bitwise complement operator you're using (~) [is implemented as an "XOR" operation with `-1` (all bits set)](https://www.artima.com/underthehood/logicP.html).  From that link:

```
tempSpock &= ~mask;
```

becomes

```
25 iload_2 // Push local variable 2 (mask).
26 iconst_m1 // Push -1.
27 ixor // Bitwise EXCLUSIVE-OR top two ints: ~mask
```

However, I can only [find instructions for XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) (and for other unary and binary operators too) for `int`s and `long`s (`float` and `double` version exist for other operators where appropriate).

So, Java must perform those promotions because there are no bytecode instructions for performing those operations on `byte`s, `short`s, or `char`s.

**Why not, JVM?**

That brings up another question:  Why doesn't the JVM support such bytecode instructions?  The answer appears to be, "Because there would be too many to encode them all in a one-byte instruction set." According to the [JVM Specification, Section 2.11.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1),

> Given the Java Virtual Machine's **one-byte opcode size**, encoding types into opcodes places pressure on the design of its instruction set. If each typed instruction supported all of the Java Virtual Machine's run-time data types, **there would be more instructions than could be represented in a byte**. Instead, the instruction set of the Java Virtual Machine provides a reduced level of type support for certain operations. In other words, the instruction set is intentionally not orthogonal. Separate instructions can be used to convert between unsupported and supported data types as necessary.

(emphasis mine)

In conclusion, the JVM's one-bytecode instruction set precludes the bytecode instructions for most operations on `byte`s, `char`s, and `short`s, necessitating unary numeric promotion and binary numeric promotion.

Comment: Your bytecode argument is nonsense. The compiler could very well add casts if this were specified by the language.  For an example see how `+=` is defined on `short`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, types smaller than `int` undergo *promotion* when used as operands to most operators.  They are effectively cast to `int` first.  Therefore, in your code above, the type of the result is `int`.  See [this section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1) of the JLS for the full details.

As for *why* Java does this, I'm not sure.  But one plausible reason is that C does this, and maintaining familiar semantics was probably a language design objective.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference to where this behavior is defined in C ?