# Behavior of bitwise xor using binary literals

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

I'm curious to know what actually happens on a bitwise comparison using binary literals. I just came across the following thing:

```
byte b1 = (new Byte("1")).byteValue();

// check the bit representation
System.out.println(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b1 & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0'));
// output: 00000001

System.out.println(b1 ^ 0b00000001);
// output: 0
```

So everything behaves as expected, the `xor` comparison equals `0`. However when trying the same with a negative number it won't work:

```
byte b2 = (new Byte("-1")).byteValue();

// check the bit representation
System.out.println(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b2 & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0'));
// output: 11111111

System.out.println(b2 ^ 0b11111111);
// output: -256
```

I would have expected that the last `xor` comparison also equals `0`. However this is only the case if I do an explicit cast of the binary literal to `byte`:

```
byte b2 = (new Byte("-1")).byteValue();

// check the bit representation
System.out.println(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b2 & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0'));
// output: 11111111

System.out.println(b2 ^ (byte)0b11111111);
// output: 0
```

For me it looks like that before the `xor` comparison both `b1` and `0b11111111` have the same bit representation so even if they get casted to `int` (or something else) the `xor` should still equal `0`. How do you come to the result of `-256` which is `11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000` in binary representation? Why do I have to do an explicit cast to `byte` in order to obtain `0`?

Comment: Those are integer literals written in binary notation. What's more, binary operators promote their operands.

Comment: Alright! So I see what happens: `0b11111111` is the binary representation of `255` and is in fact an integer. So `b2` gets cast to `int` as well which (from construction) is `-1`. So what happens is a bitwise `xor` of `-1` and `255` (in 32-bit representation) which yields `-256`. If I do the cast `(byte)0b11111111` then the comparison will be done without a cast to `int` but only for the 8 bits of both expressions. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary literals without a specific cast represent 32-bit integer values, no matter how many digits there are. For example `0b00000001` is a shorthand for `0b00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001`.

Bitwise comparisons in Java use *binary numeric promotion* (see the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)). In this specific case it means that both operands get converted to `int` before the comparison is performed.

`0b11111111` is already representing an `int` (without leading `0`s) and just represents `0b00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111`, while `b2` is a byte representing the value `-1`. During the conversion to `int` the value is preserved and thus `b2` is cast to a 32-bit integer representing the same number (`-1`): `0b11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`.

The `xor` then evaluates to `0b11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000` which is the 32-bit binary representation of `-256`.

In case the `xor` comparison is performed using `(byte)0b11111111` the binary literal will also be treated as a byte and thus equivalently cast to a 32-bit integer representing `-1`.

It is important to note that binary comparisons are performed with either `double, float, long` or `int` (as specified in the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)). If there are only other types participating in the comparison (as for example `byte`) they will be converted to `int`. That is why the following piece of code will give a compilation error:

```
byte b1 = (byte)0b00000001;
byte b2 = (byte)0b00000001;
byte b3 = b1 & b2;

>>> error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
```

... because the result of a bitwise comparison of two `byte` is an `int`.

Further reading about the *why* can be done here:

- [Types and the Java Virtual Machine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1)
- [Bitwise operators in java only for integer and long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577609/bitwise-operators-in-java-only-for-integer-and-long)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `b1 ^ 0b11111111` you actually do `xor` between byte to an int
`byte` is 8 bit variable while `int` is 32 bit number.
So, what you did is:
`b1 ^ 0b(00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111)`
so when you use `xor` between the `byte` (with additional 1s before it to use it with int. 1s because it is a negetive number. If it was positive it would be 0s) and `int` the result will be an integer and in your case, -256.

When you cast the integer to `byte` you are using `xor` between two bytes and the result will be a byte.